# GIT: how to stash a file after being edited locally

Tags: git

I've run "git add file" on local file and now I'm trying stash the action.

```
git status

\# On branch feature/something

\# Changes to be committed:

\#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

\#  modified:   utils.py
```

When I run `git diff utils.py` response is Empty

How do I stash this changes I've done locally
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well it's simpler than I thought,

running command:

## "git stash"

will stash changes on all edited/added files in git repository

Comment: Please remember to add files to the index otherwise changes to untracked files may be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the command `git stash “name_of_the_file”` this will stash the modified file in the currently checked out branch.